# How to programmatically download CSV files from Google Play Developer Console using Python?

Tags: python, android, csv, google-developers-console

I am trying to download CSV files from the Google Play Developer Console. Inside the Developer Console, under Download Reports > Statistics, I can download CSV files with statistics on downloads, installations, and uninstalls of my applications.

Using the URI of the bucket that stores the data in Cloud Storage which I obtain in the Developer Console, I open the following URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/pubsite_prod_7157330435810114607, where the files are displayed. From there, being logged in with the same Gmail account as my developer account in Developer Console, I am allowed to download the CSV files one by one.

However, I want to download them using a Python script to plot the data with matplotlib:

```
import webbrowser

def download_file():
    # Download URL for the CSV file
    download_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/pubsite_prod_7157330435810114607/stats/installs/installs_com.geology_quiz_and_guide.mineralogy_202301_app_version.csv"

    # Opens the browser at Google's login URL
    webbrowser.open('https://accounts.google.com/')

    # Wait to allow time to log in manually
    input("Press Enter after you have logged into Google...")

    # Once logged in, attempt to download the file
    webbrowser.open(download_url)

    print("Downloading file...")

download_file()
```

The script does not allow me to download the file due to lack of permissions:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access denied.</Message>
    <Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.get' denied on resource (or it may not exist).</Details>
</Error>
```

Why can't I download the files if I am logged in and it's the account associated with the bucket?

Is there another way to download the CSV files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better you download the file from your bucket using a service account and the cloud storage python client.

First you generate a service account .json file which will contain your credentials so you can authenticate with the  google cloud api.

On your google cloud console, you can go to `IAM and admin`>`Service accounts`. You can create a new service account or use default, provided it has the permissions to access  the storage bucket for the project which it normally has. Create a new key for the service account and choose the `JSON` type. Store the downloaded json file at a location convenient for you maybe next to your script.

Also pip install the library `google-cloud-storage` and any dependencies.

Here is a sample code you can use to download the files from your storage bucket.

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os

# set environment variable referencing location of service account file
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "file.json" # actual path

# function to download file from bucket
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    
    # download blob to local file
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
```

So if my bucket name is `bucket1` and blob inside the bucket is `bucket1data` and i want to save to '\files\downloaded_blob`

```
download_blob('bucket1', 'bucket1data', '\files\downloaded_blob')
```

Comment: Worcking, but the only thing is the bucket that has the files can't be accesible with a credential. It is not associated to any of my GCP projects. I needed to transfer all the files to a bucket of my project and then create the credentials. I will daily need to do this. The permissions on the GCP bucket cannot be changed.

Comment: I might do it with a script in my computer, the one connected to gsutil

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with gsutil and execute the command in the bash terminal (Linux):

```
import subprocess

# Definition of commands
commands = [
    'gsutil -m cp -r "gs://pubsite_prod_7157330435810114607/earnings" .',
    'gsutil -m cp -r "gs://pubsite_prod_7157330435810114607/reviews" .',
    'gsutil -m cp -r "gs://pubsite_prod_7157330435810114607/sales" .',
    'gsutil -m cp -r "gs://pubsite_prod_7157330435810114607/stats" .'
]

# Execution of each command
for cmd in commands:
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True)
```

This script doesn't need authentication, so I think the files are public. I don't know why the 403 error in the script posted in the question.

#### EDIT

It needs authentication while installing gsutil. Read the comments from further information.

Comment: 403 status code means forbidden access. Something to do with permissions

Comment: I tried accessing your bucket using the link you provided. Getting the 403 error as well. You need to authenticate

Comment: With gsutil, it requires you to authenticate to google cloud anyway, so its already authenticated

Comment: @Mess Ok, thanks I didn't remember I authenticated while installing gsutil. I will need to check that because the GUI to plot the graphs is going to be shared with my 3 partners.

Comment: I see. In that case, you can create another service account (to be shared with your 3 partners) and control the priviledges for read access only from the bucket.